# Why is my jquery toggle class is not working on single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a jquery function for toggle effect for an icon so when I click on that icon the div will move to left and hide.. so only the icon will show on the page and when I click on that icon again the div will appear sliding from left I am able to achieve the function but the following function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".demo-icon").click(function() {
    if ($('.demo_changer').hasClass("active")) {
      $(".demo_changer").animate({
        "left": "-208px"
      }, function() {
        $('.demo_changer').toggleClass("active");
      });
    } else {
      $('.demo_changer').animate({
        "left": "0px"
      }, function() {
        $('.demo_changer').toggleClass("active");
      });
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo_changer" style="padding-top:13px">
  <div class="demo-icon customBgColor">
    <i class="fa fa-bullhorn fa-spin fa-2x"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="form_holder">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="predefined_styles">
          <div class="skin-theme-switcher">
            <a href="campaign.html" target="_blank">
              <h4>some text</h4>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any replies in advance.

Comment: You have a typo in the HTML. `</h4>` is just `/h4>`. Is this in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: @jazzyy22 Why did you remove the stack snippet I added?

Comment: hi Barmar thanks for letting me know it's a copying error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that you did not add the class `active` while pageload but yet displaying the div.

Change the below line

`<div class="demo_changer" style="padding-top:13px">`

as

`<div class="demo_changer active" style="padding-top:13px">`

While loading, your webpage shows the div but does not have the class `active` in the div tag 
and while clicking for the first time, as per your script, it finds out that there is no `active` class in the tag and then adds the class `active` and your div is already visible... I hope you understood..

---

The issue may be that, the margin in `<div class="row">` is overlapping the icon div, it might be a reason why clicking on that area does not trigger "click" event -- See image below

[image]

Try Adding css style as mentioned in image below -

[image]

Comment: as you said, "click" event does not trigger on a single click? check the answer, I have tried modifying css on your site and It does work as intended.

Comment: Hi karthikeyan i guess i was not able to express my query properly to you however i tried your suggestion but the click event is happening after the second click. Even you can check the website again by doing the same change in the inspect element before clicking the icon i guess you would have click the icon once  and then did the changes in the element anyways thanks for taking the initiative and helping me with the query looking further for any suggestion from your end thanks in advance

Comment: Hi karthikeyan thanks a lot for a quick help  & the through explaination it works

Comment: Hi Dev, If my answer solved your issue, and u got the desired result. If you like it, please accept my answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `position: absolute;` or `position: relative;` for the `.demo_changer` class so that you can animate its position.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".demo-icon").click(function() {
    if ($('.demo_changer').hasClass("active")) {
      $(".demo_changer").animate({
        "left": "-208px"
      }, function() {
        $('.demo_changer').toggleClass("active");
      });
    } else {
      $('.demo_changer').animate({
        "left": "0px"
      }, function() {
        $('.demo_changer').toggleClass("active");
      });
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.demo_changer {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo_changer" style="padding-top:13px">
  <div class="demo-icon customBgColor">
    <i class="fa fa-bullhorn fa-spin fa-2x">icon</i>
  </div>
  <div class="form_holder">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="predefined_styles">
          <div class="skin-theme-switcher">
            <a href="campaign.html" target="_blank">
              <h4>some text</h4>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need too extra styles for animation block .

```
.demo_changer {
  position:relative
}
```

Here is working example.

https://jsbin.com/xikamitole/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for taking an initiative to resolve my problem Mykola but i don't thing a jquery toggle event is at all related with css since the function start executing on second click not on first click

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$(document).on('click', '.demo-icon', function() {
    if ($('.demo_changer').hasClass("active")) {
      $(".demo_changer").animate({
        "left": "-208px"
      }, function() {
        $('.demo_changer').toggleClass("active");
      });
    } else {
      $('.demo_changer').animate({
        "left": "0px"
      }, function() {
        $('.demo_changer').toggleClass("active");
      });
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: thanks luissimo for replying i tried this but it's not help full it's still working on second click once the page load